# Bash function - second parameter in a function not taken

Tags: bash, function, parameters, scripting, subshell

For some reason I cannot pass the 2nd parameter to a function which is on a another file, exactly here:

`$lsValidLocal  | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'Push "{}" "**$inFolder**"`

The **Push** function on **functions.sh** does not read the 2nd parameter **$inFolder**.

I tried several different ways, the only working way till now is exporting the variable to make it globally accessible (not a good solution though)

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#other machine
export otherachine="IP_address_otherachine"

#folders
inFolder="$HOME/folderIn"

outFolder="$HOME/folderOut"

#loading functions.sh
. /home/ec2-user/functions.sh

export lsValidLocal="lsValid $inFolder"

echo $inFolder

#execution
$lsValidLocal  | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'Push "{}" "$inFolder"'
```

functions.sh

```
function Push() { 
        local FILE=$1
        local DEST=$2

        scp $FILE $otherachine:$DEST &&
        rm $FILE ${FILE}_0 &&
        ssh $otherachine "touch ${FILE}_0"
}

function lsValid() { #from directory
        local DIR=$1

        ls $DIR/*_0  | sed 's/.\{2\}$//'
}


export -f Push
export -f Pull
export -f lsValid
```

Comment: Have you tried to display arguments of `Push` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the code you have written is that `$inFolder` is inside single quotes (`'`) which will prevent it being expanded.

```
$lsValidLocal  | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c 'Push "{}" "**$inFolder**"'
```

This will be executed as three separate layers of processes

```
bash <your scrpit>
|
\xargs ...
  |
  \bash -c Push ...
```

Your code is not transferring the value across from the outer shell to inner shell... But you are expanding the variable `inFolder` using the inner shell.  As you correctly point out it can be done with an exported environment variable.

The alternative is to have the outer shell expand it before passing to xargs.

```
$lsValidLocal  | xargs -n 1 -I {} bash -c "Push '{}' '**$inFolder**'"
```

Notice I have reversed `'` and `"` to allow `$inFolder` to be expanded before `xargs` is called.